# how to declare style properties for support library

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using appcompat v7 in my project. In the documentation it is written that we have to declare style properties  two times once using platform's style properties and the other in appcompat.R.attr properties .

" each style property that you declare must be declared twice: once using the platform's style properties (the android: properties) and once using the style properties included in the Support Library (the appcompat.R.attr properties—the context for these properties is actually your app). See the examples below for details."

**Now my question is how to declare style properties in appcompat.r.attr**

**Note**  we were told that we should not bring any changes in R file.

any Idea please

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples: they mean once with *android:* prefix, and once without.
But it seems that with new AppCompat-v7 (v21) without prefix is sufficient to styling ActionBar.